# (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)) causing segmentation fault, how?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

The code works fine on most inputs,  but for userID's whih are very long I get a segmentation fault.  My question is,  how can malloc cause a segmentation fault? simply allocating memory shouldn't cause this.   I found the problem area by using printf() statements,  it seem the malloc within my read_line() function is where the problem is because the second "read_line" does not print,  but the first before the malloc does.

thank you.
- Chris

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DELIM " " /* the delimiter */
#define MAX_CHANGE (10.0/86400.0)       /* 10kg/day */
/* seconds in a day is 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds */
#define MEM_OUT printf("%s","out of memory");

/* Defines Node structure. */
struct Node{
    char *id;
    float weight;
    int time;
    struct Node *next;
} *head, *p, *t, *last;

/* Constructor which returns a pointer to a new node. */
struct Node * new_node(int time, char *id, float w)
{   /*note malloc returns a pointer */
    struct Node *node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->time = time;
    node->id = (char *)malloc( (strlen(id) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(node->id, id); //duplicate the id, so new node has own copy.
    node->weight = w;
    node->next = NULL;
return node;    
}

/* reads in line of characters until either a EOF or '\n' is encountered
    then places a the terminator '\0' at the end */
char * read_line(FILE *stream)
{
    printf("read_line");
char * temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("read_line");
char * line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char c;
    *line = '\0';
    int i = 1; 
    //strchr()

    while( (c = getc(stream)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        //if(c == EOF) return NULL;
        //realloc(line,++i);
        strcpy(temp,line);
        line = malloc(++i * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(line,temp);
        temp = malloc(i * sizeof(char));
        *(line + (i-1)) = '\0'; 
        *(line + (i-2)) = c; 
    }
free(temp);
if( i == 1) return NULL;
return line;
}

main() {

    int lasttime = 0, timestamp, duration, tokens;
    char * userID = NULL;
    char * lastuserID = NULL;
    char * line = NULL;
    float weight,lastweight,change,changePerTime;
    head = new_node(0,"",0.0);
    last = head;

    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\School\\York\\cse\\2031 Software Tools\\Labs\\6\\input.txt","r");

    while( (line = read_line(fp)) != '\0') {
        printf("%s\n",line);
        //free(userID);
        line = strtok(line, " \n");
        if (line == NULL || sscanf(line,"%d",&timestamp) < 1 || timestamp == 0){
            printf("%s\n","Invalid time");
            continue;
            }
        line = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        if(line == NULL || isdigit(line[0]) || line[0] == '.') {
            printf("Illegal userID");
            //free(line);
            continue;
            }
        userID = (char * )malloc( (strlen(line)+1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(userID,line);
        strcat(userID," ");
        do{
            line = strtok(NULL," \n");      
        if(line != NULL && !isdigit(line[0]) && line[0] != '.'){    
            strcat(userID,line ); // adds ' ' and '\0'
            strcat(userID," "); 
            }
        }while(line != NULL && line[0] != '.' && !isdigit(line[0]) );
        userID[strlen(userID)-1] = '\0'; //erases the tailing space.
        if(strlen(userID) > 179){
            printf("Illegal userID\n");
            printf("mid"); 
            continue;
            printf("%s\n","after" );
            } 
        if(line != NULL)
            tokens = sscanf(line,"%f", &weight);
        if(line == NULL || tokens < 1 || weight < 30.0 || weight > 300.0)
            {printf("Illegal weight\n"); continue; }
        if (lasttime >= timestamp){
            printf("Nonmonotonic timestamps\n"); 
            continue;
            }
            lasttime = timestamp;

            // record is valid apst this point.
            /* t = last occurence of this userID, p = last userID*/
            for(p = head, t = NULL; p != NULL; p = p->next)
            {   
                if(strcmp(userID,p->id) == 0)
                    t=p;    
                last = p; // set last to last p.
            }
            if(t == NULL)
                printf("OK newuser\n");         
            else if(t != NULL)
            {
                duration = timestamp - t->time;
                change = weight - t->weight;
                changePerTime = change / duration;
                if(changePerTime < -MAX_CHANGE || changePerTime > MAX_CHANGE)
                    printf("Suspiciously large weight change\n");
                else
                    printf("OK\n");
            }
            /* add new node to end of list */
            last->next = new_node(timestamp,userID,weight);
            /* update lastnode */
            last = last->next;      
        free(line); 
        }
       fclose(fp);

/* count sum of id's for last valid user*/
    int count=0;
    for(p = head->next; p !=NULL; p=p->next)
    {
        if(strcmp(last->id,p->id) == 0)
            count++;
    }
//fclose(f);  // use if input from file is uncommented
// adds 1 to both demensions to hole axis
int tHeight = 11;
int tWidth = count + 1;
int qHeight = 10;
int qWidth= count;


/* builds the barchart */
    char bc[tHeight][tWidth];  // + 1 for y-axis

    /* draws axis and orgin */
    int a,b;
    for(a=0; a<tHeight; a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<tWidth; b++)
        {
            if(a == qHeight && b == 0)
                bc[a][b] = '+';
            else if(a < tHeight && b == 0)
                bc[a][b] = '|';
            else if(a == qHeight && b > 0)
                bc[a][b] = '-';
        }
    }       

    /* prints the bars */
    int j=1, i, k, bh;
    for(p = head; p != NULL, j < tWidth; p=p->next)
    {               
        if(strcmp(last->id,p->id) == 0)
        {
            for(i = 9, k=0, bh = (int)(p->weight / 30);i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(k < bh) 
                {
                    bc[i][j] = '*'; 
                    k++; // barheight
                }
                else 
                    bc[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        j++;
        }                                           
    }
/* prints the barchart */
    int m, n;
    for(m=0; m < tHeight; m++)
    {           
        for(n=0; n < tWidth; n++)
        {           
            printf("%c",bc[m][n]);
        }
        printf("%c",'\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't trust printf for finding segfault position. Many time, some printf are still in the buffer when segfault occur. I **strongly** advise the use of a debugger.

Comment: I had no idea,  the prof professed it as being the best debugger (print statements that is).  I will try and get GDB working.

Comment: If you use prints for debugging, end them with a new line at least. Otherwise output is deferred until the next newline, which never happens.

Comment: `(char*)malloc(sizeof(char))` == `malloc(1)`

Comment: Yes, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so all instances of `* sizeof(char)` can be removed.

Comment: I didn't know, I thought I had to specify the pointer type when using malloc?    malloc(1),   soooo much cleaner!

Comment: @kiwicomb123: `malloc` takes a `size_t`, so it can be any `size_t`.  of course, most types have variable size, so you'll write something like `foo *f = malloc(sizeof(foo))` or, more canonically, `foo *f = malloc(sizeof *f)`. This continues to work properly if the type of `f` changes, whereas `sizeof(foo)` does not.  Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C

Comment: @MOehm: Or follow each `printf` with `fflush(stdout)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!   The issue wasn't the read_line function at all, it was the memory allocation for the userID string.  Moving the malloc() for the user to the beginning of the loop fixed the problem.

The amount of memory allocated for the userID portion of the line was based on the the length of the whole line.  eg:  malloc(strlen(line)+2). However this was done after calling strtok() on the line a few times,  which would allocate a memory block shorter than the length of the entire line.  This is because strtok() places null terminators '\0' 's at every instance of the specified delimiter in the line, and strlen() only counts the length from the passed character pointer to the first '\0' it encounters.

Anyway,  thanks for your help guys!

-Chris

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DELIM " " /* the delimiter */
#define MAX_CHANGE (10.0/86400.0)       /* 10kg/day */
/* seconds in a day is 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds */

/* Defines Node structure. */
struct Node{
    char *id;
    float weight;
    int time;
    struct Node *next;
} *head, *p, *t, *last;

/* Constructor which returns a pointer to a new node. */
struct Node * new_node(int time, char *id, float w)
{   /*note malloc returns a pointer */
    struct Node *node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->time = time;
    node->id = malloc(strlen(id) + 1);
    strcpy(node->id, id); //duplicate the id, so new node has own copy.
    node->weight = w;
    node->next = NULL;
return node;    
}

/* reads in line of characters until either a EOF or '\n' is encountered
    then places a the terminator '\0' at the end */
char * read_line(FILE *in)
{
    int i = 1;
    char * s = NULL;
    char c;
    do{
    s = realloc(s,i);  //strlen does not work on NULL strings
    if(s == NULL || s == "")
    {
        printf("%s\n","out of memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    *(s + (i-1)) = '\0'; // ensures null terminated
    if(i > 1) 
    *(s + (i-2)) = c;
    i++;
    }
    while( (c = getc(in)) != EOF && c != '\n' );
    if (c == '\n')
        return s;
    else if(c == EOF)
        return NULL;
}

main() {

    int lasttime = 0, timestamp, duration, tokens;
    char * userID = NULL;
    char * lastuserID = NULL;
    char * line = NULL;
    float weight,lastweight,change,changePerTime;
    head = new_node(0,"",0.0);
    last = head;

    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\School\\York\\cse\\2031 Software Tools\\Labs\\6\\tests\\04.in","r");

    while((line = read_line(fp)) != NULL) {
        userID = malloc(strlen(line)+2); // max userID length is line length** 
        line = strtok(line, " \n");
        if (line == NULL || sscanf(line,"%d",&timestamp) < 1 || timestamp == 0){
            printf("%s\n","Invalid time");
            continue;
            }
        line = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        if(line == NULL || isdigit(line[0]) || line[0] == '.') {
            printf("%s\n","Illegal userID");
            //free(line);
            continue;
            }
        strcpy(userID,line);
        strcat(userID," ");
        do{
            line = strtok(NULL," \n");      
        if(line != NULL && !isdigit(line[0]) && line[0] != '.'){    
            strcat(userID,line ); // adds ' ' and '\0'
            strcat(userID," "); 
            }
        }while(line != NULL && line[0] != '.' && !isdigit(line[0]) );
        userID[strlen(userID)-1] = '\0'; //erases the tailing space.
        if(strlen(userID) > 179){
            printf("Illegal userID\n"); 
            free(userID);
            free(line);
            continue;
            } 
        if(line != NULL)
            tokens = sscanf(line,"%f", &weight);
        if(line == NULL || tokens < 1 || weight < 30.0 || weight > 300.0)
            {printf("Illegal weight\n"); continue; }
        if (lasttime >= timestamp){
            printf("Nonmonotonic timestamps\n"); 
            continue;
            }
            lasttime = timestamp;

            // record is valid apst this point.
            /* t = last occurence of this userID, p = last userID*/
            for(p = head, t = NULL; p != NULL; p = p->next)
            {   
                if(strcmp(userID,p->id) == 0)
                    t=p;    
                last = p; // set last to last p.
            }
            if(t == NULL)
                printf("OK newuser\n");         
            else if(t != NULL)
            {
                duration = timestamp - t->time;
                change = weight - t->weight;
                changePerTime = change / duration;
                if(changePerTime < -MAX_CHANGE || changePerTime > MAX_CHANGE)
                    printf("Suspiciously large weight change\n");
                else
                    printf("OK\n");
            }
            /* add new node to end of list */
            last->next = new_node(timestamp,userID,weight);
            /* update lastnode */
            last = last->next;  
            free(line); 

        } // end of input loop
       fclose(fp);

/* count sum of id's for last valid user*/
    int count=0;
    for(p = head->next; p !=NULL; p=p->next)
    {
        if(strcmp(last->id,p->id) == 0)
            count++;
    }
//fclose(f);  // use if input from file is uncommented
// adds 1 to both demensions to hole axis
int tHeight = 11;
int tWidth = count + 1;
int qHeight = 10;
int qWidth= count;


/* builds the barchart */
    char bc[tHeight][tWidth];  // + 1 for y-axis

    /* draws axis and orgin */
    int a,b;
    for(a=0; a<tHeight; a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<tWidth; b++)
        {
            if(a == qHeight && b == 0)
                bc[a][b] = '+';
            else if(a < tHeight && b == 0)
                bc[a][b] = '|';
            else if(a == qHeight && b > 0)
                bc[a][b] = '-';
        }
    }       

    /* prints the bars */
    int j=1, i, k, bh;
    for(p = head; p != NULL, j < tWidth; p=p->next)
    {               
        if(strcmp(last->id,p->id) == 0)
        {
            for(i = 9, k=0, bh = (int)(p->weight / 30);i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(k < bh) 
                {
                    bc[i][j] = '*'; 
                    k++; // barheight
                }
                else 
                    bc[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        j++;
        }                                           
    }
/* prints the barchart */
    int m, n;
    for(m=0; m < tHeight; m++)
    {           
        for(n=0; n < tWidth; n++)
        {           
            printf("%c",bc[m][n]);
        }
        printf("%c",'\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `malloc` calls are not causing a segmentation fault. But your use of them later on could be.

**Some Items of Note**

- Your `printf("read line")` statements will not print out immediately when called because the output is buffered. If you want them to print right away, do `printf("read line\n")`. You'll then see that both execute and your code that uses the tiny buffer you allocated will cause the crash.
- In your `while` loop, you are doing more `malloc` calls and assigning the returns to variables, like `temp` and `line`, without freeing the prior memory pointers that `temp` and `line` hold, thus causing some memory leaks. Your commented out `realloc` was the better thought process: `line = realloc(line, ++i * sizeof(*line));`. Similarly for `temp`.

---

**Memory Allocation Problem**

One very problematic area is here:

```
    userID = (char * )malloc( (strlen(line)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(userID,line);
    strcat(userID," ");
```

`userID` can hold the length of the string in `line` (`strlen(line)`) plus one more byte. But that one more byte is needed for the null terminator. Your `strcat(userID, " ")` will write past the length of the allocated buffer for `userID` by one byte.

Comment: But I dynamically increase the size in the while loop within the read_line function.  the purpose of allocating the 1 byte was to initialize the pointer,  then in the loop the block of memory pointed to by line increases as the input increases.   I initially tried using realloc()  but it caused errors when it reverted to malloc()  for certain resized memory blocks.

Comment: @kiwicomb123 yes, I do see that now. But overall the logic is really quite convoluted and full of memory leaks. If you fix your `printf` issues, it might point you further toward the segmentation fault area.

Comment: I added \n to the printf's  but no closer to finding the problem, (only first of the  printf("read_line\n") 's work.)  GDB says "0x75368dd2 in strcat() from c:\winodows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll

Comment: @kiwicomb123 see my added comments in my answer. I did find at least one real problem.